# Find the Foreign Keys Associated with a Given Primary Key

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, metadata

I want a way to establish which columns in a given database are joined via PK/FK relationships. I can return the PK/FK information for a given table via

```
SELECT *  
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS cu 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT tc.* 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS tc 
    WHERE tc.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = 'MyDatabase'  
        AND tc.TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'  
        /*AND tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'*/
        AND tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME);
GO
```

but for a PK returned from such a query how do I establish the associated FK (assuming there is one)?

I know you can also get the referenced tables via:

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME = name, 
       FOREIGN_SCHEMA = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id), 
       FOREIGN_TABLE = OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id), 
       REFERENCED_SCHEMA = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referenced_object_id), 
       REFERENCED_TABLE = OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) 
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) = 'MyTable';
GO
```

but I am struggling now to get the explicit column references.

I am creating a script generator for QlikView. To generate the script I need the constraints and the associated links. I need all of the constraint information for any given column (if any).

I want to construct a database class that holds all the information for a given database. This class structure `database.table.column.constraints` will then be used to get the matches between different columns on PK/FKs.

Clearly some columns will have FKs only and in this case I also want to retrieve the PK information of the corresponding key; some will have only PKs and then I want the reverse. Some of course can have both.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here's a simple query to match up foreign keys to their referenced tables/columns:

```
SELECT
    o1.name AS FK_table,
    c1.name AS FK_column,
    fk.name AS FK_name,
    o2.name AS PK_table,
    c2.name AS PK_column,
    pk.name AS PK_name,
    fk.delete_referential_action_desc AS Delete_Action,
    fk.update_referential_action_desc AS Update_Action
FROM sys.objects o1
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys fk
        ON o1.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
        ON fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c1
        ON fkc.parent_object_id = c1.object_id
        AND fkc.parent_column_id = c1.column_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c2
        ON fkc.referenced_object_id = c2.object_id
        AND fkc.referenced_column_id = c2.column_id
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o2
        ON fk.referenced_object_id = o2.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.key_constraints pk
        ON fk.referenced_object_id = pk.parent_object_id
        AND fk.key_index_id = pk.unique_index_id
ORDER BY o1.name, o2.name, fkc.constraint_column_id
```

The output has eight columns: the table and column names for the foreign keys (FK_table, FK_column), the names of the foreign-key constraints (FK_name), the referenced PK or unique index table and column names (PK_table, PK_column), the name of the referenced PK or unique index (PK_name), and the update/delete cascade actions (Delete_Action, Update_Action).

(Edited to add some more output columns.)

**EDIT:** I'm back 6 years later with an improved version of this. I realized that the original query doesn't really handle multi-column foreign keys well, and I also wanted to be able to quickly identify disabled, untrusted, or unindexed foreign keys. So here's the new version that corrects all of that.

Multi-column keys are shown as comma-separated lists in `FK_columns` and `PK_columns`, using the traditional `FOR XML`/`STUFF` abuse. The `FK_indexes` column shows the names of any indexes on the foreign-key table that could potentially be used to satisfy seeks using the foreign-key columns (mainly for optimizing deletes or updates to the primary key table). If it's `NULL`, then you've got an unindexed foreign key. You can tweak the `ORDER BY`, or add a `WHERE` clause (commented out below) if you want to sort by the PK table name, filter for specific PK/FK tables, etc.

```
SELECT
    fk.is_disabled,
    fk.is_not_trusted,
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(o1.object_id) AS FK_schema,
    o1.name AS FK_table,
    --Generate list of columns in referring side of foreign key
    STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ', ' + c1.name AS [text()]
            FROM sys.columns c1 INNER
                JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
                    ON c1.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
                    AND c1.column_id = fkc.parent_column_id
            WHERE fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 2, '') AS FK_columns,
    --Look for any indexes that will fully satisfy the foreign key columns
    STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ', ' + i.name AS [text()]
            FROM sys.indexes i
            WHERE i.object_id = o1.object_id
                AND NOT EXISTS ( --Find foreign key columns that don't match the index key columns
                    SELECT fkc.constraint_column_id, fkc.parent_column_id
                    FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
                    WHERE fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
                    EXCEPT
                    SELECT ic.key_ordinal, ic.column_id
                    FROM sys.index_columns ic
                    WHERE ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
                )
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 2, '') AS FK_indexes,
    fk.name AS FK_name,
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(o2.object_id) AS PK_schema,
    o2.name AS PK_table,
    --Generate list of columns in referenced (i.e. PK) side of foreign key
    STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ', ' + c2.name AS [text()]
            FROM sys.columns c2
                INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
                    ON c2.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
                    AND c2.column_id = fkc.referenced_column_id
            WHERE fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 2, '') AS PK_columns,
    pk.name AS PK_name,
    fk.delete_referential_action_desc AS Delete_Action,
    fk.update_referential_action_desc AS Update_Action
FROM sys.objects o1
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys fk
        ON o1.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o2
        ON fk.referenced_object_id = o2.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.key_constraints pk
        ON fk.referenced_object_id = pk.parent_object_id
        AND fk.key_index_id = pk.unique_index_id
--WHERE o2.name = 'Company_Address'
ORDER BY o1.name, o2.name
```

Answer (score 8):

This query nets you all of the FK relationships in the database - FK constraint name, schema/table of referencing table, referencing column name, schema/table of referenced table, and referenced column name. There will be multiple rows for a multi-column constraint.

```
SELECT 
    FK = OBJECT_NAME(pt.constraint_object_id),
    Referencing_table = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(pt.parent_object_id))
            + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(pt.parent_object_id)),
    Referencing_col = QUOTENAME(pc.name), 
    Referenced_table = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(pt.referenced_object_id)) 
            + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(pt.referenced_object_id)),
    Referenced_col = QUOTENAME(rc.name)
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns AS pt
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS pc
ON pt.parent_object_id = pc.[object_id]
AND pt.parent_column_id = pc.column_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS rc
ON pt.referenced_column_id = rc.column_id
AND pt.referenced_object_id = rc.[object_id]
ORDER BY Referencing_table, FK, pt.constraint_column_id;
```

If you are after the columns from a *specific* primary key constraint, and you already know the name of that PK constraint, you can write this:

```
DECLARE @PK_Constraint SYSNAME = N'Name of PK constraint';

SELECT
    FK = OBJECT_NAME(fkc.constraint_object_id),
    Referencing_table = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id))
            + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id)),
    Referencing_col = QUOTENAME(pc.name), 
    Referenced_table = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id)) 
            + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id)),
    Referenced_col = QUOTENAME(rc.name)
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkc
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS pc
ON fkc.parent_object_id = pc.[object_id]
AND fkc.parent_column_id = pc.column_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS rc
ON fkc.referenced_column_id = rc.column_id
AND fkc.referenced_object_id = rc.[object_id]
WHERE EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM sys.indexes AS i
  INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys AS fk
  ON i.[object_id] = fk.referenced_object_id
  AND i.index_id = fk.key_index_id
  AND fk.[object_id] = fkc.constraint_object_id
  AND i.name = @PK_Constraint
)
ORDER BY Referencing_table, FK, fkc.constraint_column_id;
```

If you just want to include the PK name along with the other information:

```
SELECT 
    FK = OBJECT_NAME(fkc.constraint_object_id),
    Referencing_table = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id))
            + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id)),
    Referencing_col = QUOTENAME(pc.name),
    Referenced_table = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id)) 
            + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id)),
    Referenced_col = QUOTENAME(rc.name),
    PK = pk.name
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkc
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS pc
ON fkc.parent_object_id = pc.[object_id]
AND fkc.parent_column_id = pc.column_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS rc
ON fkc.referenced_column_id = rc.column_id
AND fkc.referenced_object_id = rc.[object_id]
INNER JOIN (SELECT i.name, fk.[object_id]
  FROM sys.indexes AS i
  INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys AS fk
  ON i.[object_id] = fk.referenced_object_id
  AND i.index_id = fk.key_index_id
) AS pk
ON pk.[object_id] = fkc.constraint_object_id
ORDER BY Referencing_table, FK, fkc.constraint_column_id;
```

There are also tricks to getting the column list in, say, a comma-separated list or individual columns, instead of being spread across rows, but I'm not going to invest in modifying these queries to produce that until I know exactly which form you're after.