# Batch converting indexes to keys

Tags: sql-server, index, foreign-key, primary-key

I have a legacy MS SQL Server database where all the primary and foreign keys were created as indexes.  I am developing the new version of our software with Entity Frameworks, which I have learned expects every table to have a primary key.  So I have to convert every PK and probably every FK index to a key.

When I tried one key at a time, I found that before converting a PK I have to find and drop ALL FK indexes.

Is there a good way to make an MS SQL script to convert the indexes as a batch?  Or do I have to do the manual approach and build a script to drop each index, build all the PKs, then build all the FKs?

(I'm running MS SQL Server 2012.)

ETA the script I tried and its errors.

```
/****** Object:  Index [FK_PROJECT_ORGANIZATION]    Script Date: 7/16/2014 10:07:13 AM ******/
DROP INDEX [FK_PROJECT_ORGANIZATION] ON [dbo].[PROJECT]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [PK_ORGANIZATION]    Script Date: 7/16/2014 9:23:54 AM ******/
DROP INDEX [PK_ORGANIZATION] ON [dbo].[ORGANIZATION] WITH ( ONLINE = OFF )
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ORGANIZATION] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_ORGANIZATION] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [organization_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


/****** Object:  Index [FK_PROJECT_ORGANIZATION]    Script Date: 7/16/2014 10:07:13 AM ******/
--Re-create the index as a foreign key
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PROJECT]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PROJECT_ORGANIZATION] FOREIGN KEY([organization_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ORGANIZATION] ([organization_id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PROJECT] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PROJECT_ORGANIZATION]
GO
```

The error messages:

```
Msg 3723, Level 16, State 6, Line 3
An explicit DROP INDEX is not allowed on index 'dbo.ORGANIZATION.PK_ORGANIZATION'. It is being used for FOREIGN KEY constraint enforcement.
Msg 1913, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'PK_ORGANIZATION' already exists on table 'dbo.ORGANIZATION'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

ETA2: The CREATE TABLE script:
(ETA3 - the script generated from the legacy database.)

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ORGANIZATION]    Script Date: 7/16/2014 12:22:47 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ORGANIZATION](
    [organization_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [user_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [user_phone] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [user_email_address] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [user_password] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [org_type] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [status] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [company] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [address_1] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [address_2] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [address_3] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [city] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [state_code] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [postal_code] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [business_poc_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [business_poc_title] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [business_poc_phone] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [business_poc_cell] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [business_poc_email_address] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [business_poc_city] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [business_poc_state_code] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [url] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [datetime_created] [smalldatetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

/****** Object:  Index [PK_ORGANIZATION]    Script Date: 7/16/2014 12:22:47 PM ******/
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [PK_ORGANIZATION] ON [dbo].[ORGANIZATION]
(
    [organization_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_ORGANIZATION_company]    Script Date: 7/16/2014 12:22:47 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ORGANIZATION_company] ON [dbo].[ORGANIZATION]
(
    [company] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_ORGANIZATION_organization_id_org_type]    Script Date: 7/16/2014 12:22:47 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ORGANIZATION_organization_id_org_type] ON [dbo].[ORGANIZATION]
(
    [organization_id] ASC,
    [org_type] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_ORGANIZATION_user_email_address]    Script Date: 7/16/2014 12:22:47 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ORGANIZATION_user_email_address] ON [dbo].[ORGANIZATION]
(
    [user_email_address] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_ORGANIZATION_user_name]    Script Date: 7/16/2014 12:22:47 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ORGANIZATION_user_name] ON [dbo].[ORGANIZATION]
(
    [user_name] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: What do you mean with *"all the primary and foreign keys were created as indexes"* Are there no primary keys but only (unique) indexes? Are there no foreign key constraints but only indexes on the columns (that should have FK constraints)? The is no such thing as an *"FK index"*.

Comment: I suggest you add a sample of one table you (the legacy) database have and the command you have tried.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean.  SSMS shows every single PK and FK object in the Indexes folders for the respective tables.

Comment: @ypercube: Done.

Comment: Add the `CREATE TABLE` script. It seems your table already has PK and FK constraints.

Comment: @ypercube: Done.  The only thing I see is that the `organization_id` field is specified as `IDENTITY(1,1)`.  Could this be significant?

Comment: Did you find this `CREATE TABLE` from the Management Studio (right click, then  Script Table as > CREATE To > New Query Editor Window)?

Comment: @ypercube: Yes, that's exactly how I did it.

Comment: You need to make sure "script indexes", "script foreign keys" and "script primary keys" are all true in Tools > Options > SQL Server Object Explorer > Scripting. And no, while identity property and primary key are often use together, there is no direct correlation there. You can have an identity column that is not a PK (and not even unique), and you can obviously have a PK that is not an identity column.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: "Script foreign keys" and "script primary keys" are already `true`.  I set "script indexes" to `true` as well.

Comment: Some ideas for starting on this [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48634/unable-to-drop-non-pk-index-because-it-is-referenced-in-a-foreign-key-constraint/48636#48636), [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31720/how-to-find-the-foreign-key-associated-with-a-given-primary-key/31722#31722), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10665972/61305)...

Comment: @CodeswithHammer This doesn't match with the error messages you get when you try the `ALTER` statements. Are you sure you have only one database and not two (running the ALTER in one but getting the scripts from the other)?

Comment: OK, so the table has a `UNIQUE` and some other indexes. Does the `Project`table also have `FOREIGN KEY` constraints?

Comment: If the only thing missing is the PK constraints because they were enforced by unique indexes, I suggest you either 1: edit the question about how to convert the unique indexes to PKs (while keeping or dropping and recreating the FKs) or (if you don't really need that now) 2: we can close the question as too localized.

Comment: I'm okay with closing the question as too localized.

Answer (score 4):

If you go into your SSMS options table and look at the scripting options for object explorer do you see foreign keys and primary keys enabled? That's pretty much the only thing I can think of that may be holding you back.

[image]

Comment: Yes, those are set to `true`.

Comment: @Codes Yet your CREATE TABLE script in the question doesn't list any indexes, primary keys or foreign keys. Did you not copy it all? Did you set these options to true AFTER generating it?

Comment: @CodeswithHammer have to rebooted SSMS since enabling these options?

Comment: I had enabled those options quite some time ago, and rebooted the whole system since then.  Thanks for suggesting the solution anyway.